# Thread not getting latest value even though other thread updates in synchronized block?

Tags: java, multithreading

I wrote this program to simulate `field visibility`.

```
package com.example.threads.fieldvisibility.main;

public class ThreadVisibilityWithSyncKeyWord implements Runnable {

    private boolean stop = false;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!stop) {

            // System.out.println("stop is " + stop);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ThreadVisibilityWithSyncKeyWord test = new ThreadVisibilityWithSyncKeyWord();
        Thread t = new Thread(test);
        System.out.println("Starting Thread");
        t.start();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("Stopping Thread");

        synchronized (test) {
            test.stop = true;
        }
        t.join(5000);
        System.out.println("Thread State: " + t.getState());
    }
}
```

The program is pretty straightforward. we have two threads. Main thread does change flag "stop" to true in a `synchronized` block using "test" object.

I expected once this is set to true by main thread, it would make while loop to terminate.  But even though main thread made flag to true , the other thread doesn't see the latest value (even though it was updated in a synchronized block).

Strangely, when I uncomment `System.out.println()` (inside while) the thread does "see" the latest value and terminates.

I didn't understand this behaviour. Why the other thread isn't able to see the latest values which is update in a synchronized block of main thread. And after uncommenting `sysout`, what causes the other thread to see the latest value of the flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a thread enters a `synchronized` block, it is guaranteed to see the current state of the accessed variables by reading from shared cache/memory. Writing variables inside a `synchronized` block will guarantee that the variable is written to shared cache/memory.

Whats happening:

- `test` is created
- `main`-thread caches `test.stop`
- `test` caches `stop` that is `false`
- `test` starts
- `test` reads the value `stop` from it's local cache (!)
- `main`-thread sets `test.stop` to `true`
- because this is done synchronized, the write is done to shared cache as well
- `test` keeps reading `stop` from it's own cache, which is still `false`

When you add the printing line to the code, you have to know that `System.out.println` involves synchronization internally:

- ...
- `main`-thread sets `test.stop` to `true`
- because this is done synchronized, the write is done to shared cache as well
- `test` does the `println` and in that moment the internal synchronization causes `test` to read the new value from the shared cache

Comment: This seems to be the case. Inside while loop, i just added `synchronized(this)` (and removed `sysout`), this thread was able to read the latest values and program got terminated. So it mean to see latest values, it needs to be inside `synchronized` block, even though other thread may have updated the values in a `synchronized` block?

Comment: @CuriousMind Exactly. Or you use `volatile` for example. A thread needs the "signal" that it shall invalidate it's local cache and update it with values from the shared cache *because* some may got updated. There are many ways to do that signal. The most prominent ways are `synchronized` and `volatile`.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. I didn't want to use `volatile` (as i checked that and works fine) , I wanted to see how it can be achieved using `synchronized` key-word. It seem , for both read, write, it needs to be in `synchronized` block for "seeing" the latest values.

Comment: @CuriousMind You have to know that `volatile` and entrace/exit of `synchonized` are [memory barriers](https://www.infoq.com/articles/memory_barriers_jvm_concurrency/). When a thread passes a memory barrier, it invalidates its local cache. Invalidation means that a thread compares the values from its local cache with the values in the shared cache and does updates. A memory barrier also causes a thread to write all happened writes to the previous memory barrier into the shared cache. That's why we say a `synchronized`-block causes all writes to happen in shared cache.

Comment: Thanks so much for the additional info, very informative. Can you suggest some material which I can refer further?

Comment: @CuriousMind The related [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4) parts and [this](https://www.agner.org/optimize/). But the latter is for experts.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main issue is how the project structured if you separate the main thread class from you runnable everything would be easier.

This is working example with following results: *(Note I added 1 second sleep to the thread to avoid many printouts)*

- Starting Thread
- stop is false
- stop is false
- stop is false
- stop is false
- Stopping Thread
- stop is true
- Thread State: TERMINATED

  package com.project;

  public class Main {

  ```
  public static boolean stop = false; 

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
      ThreadVisibilityWithSyncKeyWord test = new ThreadVisibilityWithSyncKeyWord();
      Thread t = new Thread(test);  
      System.out.println("Starting Thread");
      t.start();
      Thread.sleep(5000);
      System.out.println("Stopping Thread");

      stop = true;

      t.join(5000);
      System.out.println("Thread State: " + t.getState());

  }
  ```

  }

  package com.project;

  public class ThreadVisibilityWithSyncKeyWord implements Runnable {

  ```
  @Override
  public void run() {
      while (!Main.stop) {
          try {
              Thread.sleep(1000);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          }
          System.out.println("stop is " + Main.stop);
      }
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: @CuriousMind if more than one thread gonna access the same boolean `stop`, please make sure to use atomic variables instead: 

`public class Main {
 public static AtomicBoolean stop = new AtomicBoolean(false); 

 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ..
        stop = new AtomicBoolean(true);
        ..
 }
}`

`public class ThreadVisibilityWithSyncKeyWord implements Runnable {
 @Override
 public void run() {
  while (!Main.stop.get()) {  // .get to return the boolean value from atomic
   ..
  }
 }
}`

Comment: Thanks for your inputs and suggestion. The aim is to understand a bit on what's going behind the scenes. Appreciate your help and time.